# Why does quadratic utility function imply $\mu-\sigma$ preference?

Tags: utility, preferences

Why does investors having quadratic utility function mean that their optimal portfolios can be chosen by only considering mean and variance of returns i.e. imply $\mu-\sigma$ preference?

Comment: Hint: the quadratic utility function exhibits increasing absolute risk aversion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have quadratic preferences then your utility function is:
$$ U(W) =  W - \lambda W^2$$
this implies your expected utility function looks like:
$$ E[U(W)] =  E[W - \lambda W^2] =  E[W] - \lambda E[W^2]$$
$$ =  E[W] - \lambda E[W^2 - E[W]^2 + E[W]^2]$$
$$ =  E[W] - \lambda E[W^2 - E[W]^2] - \lambda E[E[W]^2]]$$
$$ =  \mu_w - \lambda \sigma_w^2 - \lambda \mu_w^2$$

Therefore, we have established that expected utility depends only only the mean $(\mu_W)$ and variance $(\sigma^2_W)$ of wealth and the risk parameter $(\lambda)$.

Comment: Line 3 doesn't distribute the negative from $-\lambda$ to the final term. The solution should be $=\mu_w-\lambda\sigma_w^2-\lambda\mu_w^2$. [See for reference.](https://som.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/05%20Mean-Variance%20Theory%20and%20the%20CAPM.pdf)

Comment: Good catch and now fixed.